# How to display range of hours

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table storing opening hours of a restaurant as a time range in TIME format. Eg if the restaurant's opening hours are '9am-5pm', there will be 2 columns 'hours_open' and 'hours_close' where I store 9:00 in 'hours_open' and 17:00 in 'hours_close'. What I need to do is to display the range of hours eg: 9:30am 10:00am 10:30am 11:00am 11:30am until 5:00pm

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your example doesn't really make any sense can you clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
$start = strtotime('6:00am');
$end = strtotime('09:00am');
$range = array();
while ($start !== $end)
{
    $start = strtotime('+30 minutes',$start);
    $range[] = date('h:ia', $start);
}
print_r($range);
```

Comment: I am using jquery time-picker to display hours.what I want to do is to choose the hour from time-picker and display available time which is store in database. sorry for my English.

Comment: And what's the problem there? Just pass data from the db to time-picker.

Comment: for example I choose 2pm from time-picker and then I should display hours until closing time eg 6pm as follow: 2:00 2:30 3:00 3:30 until 6pm

Answer (score 1):

> can anyone point me in the right direction?

Of course, here is everything you will need:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php
- 30 m = 1800 s
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I love your minesweeper game

Answer (score 0):

ON my current project I had to loop trough the 24 hours of the day ... and wanted them to be displayed in a certain format.

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H'); // creating the interval for 1hour
$date = new DateTime();    
$end = clone($date);
$hoursRange = new DatePeriod($date, $interval ,$end->modify("+24 hours"));
```

And then all I had was to iterate trough the hoursRange values using a foreach.

```
foreach ($hoursRange as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value->format('ga');
}
```