# Result an array with the duration every half hour

Tags: php

I want to do a function to give me an array of the time range like the following :

```
// passing FROM, TO ( times to the function ) 
function time( '11:00', '13:00' ) {

}


// i want to get it like the following 
[ 0 => '11:00', 1 => '11:30', '2' => '12:00', 3 => '12:30', 4 => '01:00' and so on .... ]
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263143/how-to-display-range-of-hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hourRange = range(strtotime('00:00'), strtotime('23:50'), 10 * 60);

foreach($hourRange as $time){
    $date = date("H:i",$time);
    echo $date . "\n";
}
```

https://gist.github.com/adililhan/cc172f0eed55f6968b10