# Given a UNIX timestamp, how do I list all months and years from it till now in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I've this difficult problem. I've a unix timestamp, such as `1280102221`, which corresponds to `25 Jul 2010`. What I want to do is list all months/years since that day till now. In my example it would be:

```
Jul 2010
Aug 2010
Sep 2010
...
Oct 2014
Nov 2014
```

How do I do this?

Here is code I tried:

```
<?php
    $timestamp = 1280102221;
    $end = 1310000000;

    for ($i = $timestamp; $i < $end; $i+= 24*30*3600) {
        echo $i . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263143/how-to-display-range-of-hours

Replace the minutes with months

Comment: where is your code? what did you try?

Comment: @Dima I no code - don't know what to do...

Comment: @Typoheads where exactly replace?

Comment: @Dima I now add codes. Please check. It's a bit of mistakes now... It doesn't list month and year it only echos UNIX ts.

Comment: @bodacydo In the example in the link I posted, there are 30 minutes added at each iteration: strtotime('+30 minutes',$start); You need to replace these 30 minutes with 1 month.

Comment: @Typoheads Can u post answer in here so I can give you all the sweet juicy karma, upvote you and accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$timestamp = 1280102221;
$end = 1310000000;
$range = array();
while ($timestamp <= $end)
{
    $range[] = date('M Y', $timestamp);
    $timestamp = strtotime('+1 month', $timestamp);
}
print_r($range);
?>
```